# Linux Data Model and primitive types size

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel, primitive-types

I know that the following data models exist:

- 32 bit *nix    : **ILP32**
- 32 bit Windows : **ILP32**
- 32 bit OS X    : **ILP32**
- 64 bit *nix    : **LP64**
- 64 bit Windows : **LLP64**
- 64 bit OSX     : **LP64**

http://www.unix.org/whitepapers/64bit.html

The 64 bit version of the Linux kernel uses the LP64 data model (http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html).

**UPDATE**

C++03 Standard $5.3.3/1

> sizeof(char), sizeof(signed char) and sizeof(unsigned char) are 1; the
>   result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   **implementation-defined**. [Note: in particular,sizeof(bool) and
>   sizeof(wchar_t) are implementation-defined.69)

So the real question is: 
does the compiler (e.g. gcc) take into account the data model chosen by the OS (linux for example)?

Comment: What about the compiler used to compile the OS?

Comment: Ron, both the languages don't define the size of the primitive type. The question is valid and I know that these are two different language. The point here is between the OS (data model chosen) and the compilers.

Comment: @Ron: no! Both the C and C++ the standard does not define the size of the primitive type! exception for char, float and double.

Comment: What do you mean "LP64 gcc"? gcc on x86 may compile for ARM targets, so it is irrelevant where compiler is run, it matters how it generates the code (based on `-m32`/`-m64` options in this case).

Comment: @myaunt: good point! Rephrased and removed the example which was confusing. The real point maybe is how does gcc choose the size of the primitive types? does it take in count the data model?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. If you compile for the host OS, of course the compiler will take into account the data model. If it didn't do that, it would create bad executables.

Comment: Most 64-bit systems can run both 32 or 64-bit executables.  gcc decides based on the arguments you give it, not based on external factors.

Comment: although your opinion is really valuable  I need an answer proving what you're saying.

Comment: So you basically questioning common sense? Why do compilers create an executable which actually can run on the host OS? Why do we need to prove this? (please use @<username> if you want to reply to someone)

Comment: @Kasper still not sure what you're asking, are you asking how gcc defines [target machines](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Desc.html#Machine-Desc) and [target macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Target-Macros.html#Target-Macros) ?

Comment: @PeterT: "does the compiler (e.g. gcc) take into account the data model chosen by the OS (linux for example)?"    that's what I'm asking. Thanks

Comment: @geza: absolutely not geza, don't misunderstand me, please. I'd just like an answer (proving what you are saying) and not an opinion : that is what stackoverflow ultimately is, right?... I'm sure gcc internally somewhere make this decision (i.e.: int = 16 or 32 bit? etc ...).

Comment: Your question is: "does the compiler (e.g. gcc) take into account the data model chosen by the OS (linux for example)?". The answer is yes, because if it didn't, it would make an executable which may not run on the OS.  The evidence is that if you compile something, it will work. If you're interested in how gcc decides the data model (i.e. sizeof(int), etc.), then ask that. I'm not an expert of gcc, but maybe these default settings are determined when gcc is configured (before gcc is compiled).

Comment: @Kasper then the answer is "it takes into account the configuration for the specified target". If you didn't specify a target it uses a default target. The default target is usually listed in  the output of "gcc -v". So the answer is: it depends on how you configured the gcc instance you're using

Comment: Thanks a lot @PeterT :-)  just now I'm looking into the configuration file of some target + gcc source code. I've discovered that gcc take the pbABI of the specific target as reference/input for the definition of the primitives size.   P.S.: you should write your comment as answer as definitely clarified/closed my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compiler compiles for a specific target. Some compilers only have one target or a very limited set of targets. Since you asked for gcc as an example then looking at their documentation reveals their formats for [`Machine Descriptions`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Machine-Desc.html#Machine-Desc) and [`Target Files`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Target-Macros.html#Target-Macros).

[Their documentation mentions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Target-Options.html)

> By default, GCC compiles code for the same type of machine that you are using. However, it can also be installed as a cross-compiler

So make sure to check to output of `gcc -v` or `gcc -dumpmachine` to see what the default target is.